# Rigid Body Simulation and moving plane

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, cell-fracture

I want to make a stone (active) break into a bunch of fragments (cell fracture). The fragments are hitting a plane. However, the plane is not static but rotating towards the fragments. I want the surface (passive) to hit the fragments and affect them with its movement, just like a tennis racket that hits some stones. The problem is, the pieces fall through the plane as if it does not exist. Can someone tell me what's going on? I appreciate your help!

[image: Rotating Plane]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume you want to make something like this:

[image]

Make the plane rigid body passive, animated, shape mesh

Make the cell fractures rigid body active, shape mesh

animate the rotation of the plane.

Hit play.

If you want special help for your blend file, please provide it so we can tell you what you did wrong.

Hint: for every simulation: always apply scale & rotation

here is the blend file so you can check it out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!!! So awesome!

Comment: You are welcome